# Python OS PostreSQL and quotes

Tags: python, bash, postgresql, psql

I can find plenty here about quotes in PSQL but nothing that quite fits this problem.

First it's a kludge. I know it's a kludge but I think I'm stuck with it (open to other alternatives though)

I have a near black box third-party linux appliance to which I have limited access I have bash, python and psql to work with. I don't have psycopg2 or any other pg libraries.

The DB I have to work with uses case-sensitive table names that need to be quoted (don't ask...)

So, at the moment I write OS shell commands to get data which I then fiddle about with and convert to JSON for my needs

A simple example:

```
pg_str = "psql -U pword dbname -A -t -c "
sql = "SELECT * FROM \"Addresses\" WHERE id=999"
os_str = pg_str + "\'" + sql + "\'" + ";"
data = string.split(os.popen(os_str).read())
```

No problem with that. I'm not claiming it's pretty, but it works (remember I can't import any db libraries...)

It all goes wrong when I have a where clause on a text field:

```
pg_str = "psql -U pword dbname -A -t -c "
sql = "SELECT * FROM \"Addresses\" WHERE town='london'"
os_str = pg_str + "\'" + sql + "\'" + ";"
data = string.split(os.popen(os_str).read())
```

Too many quote combinations to cope with...?

I've obviously tried lots of escape combinations and have been googling for several hours, but every solution seems to require libraries that I haven't got access to.

I'm no python or psql expert - this is about my current limit. I feel sure that I'm going about it the wrong way  but am currently beaten on figuring out the right way...

Comment: The easy way out is to avoid MixedCase table/column names. Really, it will help a lot.

Comment: @wildplasser - If it was in my power to do so - believe me, I would. I'm sure it seemed like a good idea at the time to someone.

Comment: Well, in the optimal case: unquoted names are treated as case-insignificant. Just remove the quotes and let the damage happen! People who use *both* MyIdentifier and myidentifier deserve to lose. Chances are small that any collisions will occur. (you could check by inspecting the catalogs) There still is a problem with frameworks that *always* "quote" their identifiers, though.

Comment: @wildplasser No, postgres converts unquoted identifier names to all lower case. If quotes are never used around a given identifier it's effectively case insensitive, but since the table names here actually have upper-case letters those names need to be quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There's no need to `\` escape `'` characters inside of `"` strings.
2. You can use `"""` strings to avoid needing to escape `"` characters.
3. Use string.replace to quote `'` characters for the shell, by replacing them with `'\''`. The resulting string will need to be surrounded by unescaped `'` characters when passed to the shell.

Using these rules, the SQL string can be made easily readable and editable:

```
pg_str = "psql -U pword dbname -A -t -c "
sql = """SELECT * FROM "Addresses" WHERE town='london'"""
sql = sql.replace("'", "'\\''")
os_str = pg_str + "'" + sql + "'" + ";"
data = string.split(os.popen(os_str).read())
```

Comment: OK Thanks everyone - got there.
I left the double quote escaped and used replace on the singles.
It's still a kludge but's a working kludge.
Although I admit to feeling a smug (and a little surprised) that no-one has said I'm going about it in completely the wrong way.
Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [@qqx provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13637764/939860): you can use [**dollar-quoting**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) instead of single-quotes to make it easier:

```
pg_str = "psql -U pword dbname -A -t -c "
sql = """'SELECT * FROM "Addresses" WHERE town = $$london$$'"""
data = string.split(os.popen(pg_str + sql).read())
```

BTW: a trailing semicolon (;) is optional for a single SQL command.

Comment: I'm having some problems apply these to a query that is built up concatenated over multiple lines. The query I'm running is complex with lots of joins over about 15 line of sql += "..."